# Extracting 'list of items' data validation criteria info to a cell in google sheets

Tags: validation, google-sheets, text-extraction

I have a google sheet that contains a list of technical settings and rules.
Each rule is store in 1 row and across 5 columns (number, name , notes, condition, action).

When a rule has more than one condition (or action), all conditions are stored 1 cell and are displayed using the data validation 'list of items' setting.

I need a way to extract the information contained in the 'data validation' list of items criteria field (as per image) into a cell.  This sheet contains hundreds of data validation cells across which the same action has to be performed.

At the moment my only solution is to open the data validation dialog box and copy/paste the content of the criteria field into a cell but this is unsustainable.  any help would be greatly appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4nXG.png)

Comment: This spreadsheet is automatically populated by a script, that I did not write.  It's unfortunate but still tremendously useful..

Comment: Welcome. Would you please give an example of a single criteria scenario where the data is supplied in one row across 5 columns. Would you please give an example of a multiple condition scenario: what data appears in one row across the five column, and give an example of the **full** list that appears in the data validation cell? Is this a one-off exercise, or something that you will do repeatedly? If repeatedly, to what extent do you have the ability to influence the design of the import data. Lastly, would you please share your spreadsheet, or at least a non-confidential version? Thanks.

Comment: [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation#getcriteriavalues) has a good code example for `getCriteriaValues`. It's an excellent starting point.

Comment: FWIW, one of the conditions in your example is: `if context.a.action isset`. isset is a php command which makes for intrigue about how these php commands make their way into a Google Sheet.